# Are there any instructions in x86 assembly that exist only in 64-bit mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, protected-mode

Some old x86 instructions are undefined in 64-bit mode.  For instance `LDS`, `LES` and `LSS`, or short opcodes of the `INC r16` (`40 + rw`) and `INC r32` (`40 + rd`) instructions.

Are there any instructions that are defined only in 64-bit mode, and not in 32-bit protected mode?

**Edit:**  The context is development of an x86 processor.  I want to make sure I'm compatible to the spec.

Comment: I guess you will get better answers if you elaborate a bit why you ask this. What's the problem you want to solve?

Comment: It's part of a study I'm doing to compare the two

Comment: Intel counts `inc r64` and `inc r32` as different instructions. Do you consider them different too?

Answer (score 5):

There is an addressing mode, which has no counterpart in 32 bit: Instruction pointer relative addressing. In 32 bit mode, this is only available with branches (aka branch offset), in 64 bit mode you can form effective addresses for any memory operand relative to the (r)ip.

So, the instruction

```
mov rbx,$100[rip]
```

does exist in x86-64, while

```
mov ebx,$100[eip]
```

does not in x86.

Answer (score 5):

From Intel's Architectures Software Developer's Manual, Volume 2C Appendix A (Opcode Map):

Table A-1. Superscripts Utilized in Opcode Tables

...

**o64** Instruction is only available when in 64-bit mode

...

Searching the tables, the following instructions appear with that superscript:

1. REX prefixes (not really an instruction but still)
2. MOVSXD
3. SYSCALL, SYSRET
4. SWAPGS

A few additional instructions which are variants of existing ones are listed in section 5.16 (64-BIT MODE INSTRUCTIONS):

1. CDQE Convert doubleword to quadword
2. CMPSQ Compare string operands
3. CMPXCHG16B Compare RDX:RAX with m128
4. LODSQ Load qword at address (R)SI into RAX
5. MOVSQ Move qword from address (R)SI to (R)DI
6. MOVZX (64-bits) Move doubleword to quadword, zero-extension
7. STOSQ Store RAX at address RDI

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside old instructions that now operate on 64 bit registers (they are really new instructions as they use a distinct binary representation), I can think of at least two instructions that are 64-bit only: `syscall` and `sysret` instructions.

Comment: 64-bit registers are specified with REX.W, which is a byte beginning with 0x4, and which maps to `INC` in 32-bit mode, so they're not really new instructions.

Comment: Nathan: 64-bit registers are specified with REX.W... which makes them have a distinct binary value, and make them new instructions, at least as far as Intel marketing goes.

Answer (score -1):

You can always look into the different manuals at http://www.intel.com/products/processor/index.htm?iid=dev_center+tech_hw_design+prods+processors to find such instructions. Will be a lot of work tough ;)

Comment: Yes, I have those.  That's just what I'm trying to avoid :)

Answer (score -1):

the opposite is much easier to come up with;)  like cmpxchg8b .... you'd never use that one in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score -1):

PUSHA exists only in 32 bit mode. It doesnot exist in 64 bit mode